# import JS6 Class

Tags: javascript, import

I am trying to import **Core** js class (files located in one directory)

```
//app.js

 import { Core }  from 'core.js';

 let core = new Core('urlRoot', 'workers');
```

```
//core.js

export class Core{

  constructor (urlRoot, pageName) {
    console.log(urlRoot);
  }
}
```

And getting error "**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {**"  What is wrong here ?

Comment: What line exactly you are getting this error?

Comment: first error: import { Core }  from './core.js';

Comment: i guess you didn't use type='module',,,example:<script src="test2.js" type="module"></script>  then,you can import in the test2.js

Comment: Show us how you are running `app.js`

Comment: What environment are you trying this in? Nodejs? browser (which one)? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first error:

```
import { Core }  from './core.js';
```

second error, i guess you miss the `type="module"`

```
<script src="app.js" type="module"></script>
```

then you can do the `import` in the app.js

Comment: How do you know the OP even used a `<script>` tag?

Comment: Well, node gives a different error :p - although, so do browsers that support modules too

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {` is what Chrum outputs if you forget `type="module"` ... so, yes, this is the correct answer

Comment: @DmitriyShaydurov,you can close this question by accepting my answer because it has been solved

Comment: @xianshenglu , sorry I don't know how to do it. Next to your question I have only "share" and "edit" options

Comment: @DmitriyShaydurov,https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work